# AngularJS initializing $scope of directive/controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I put the `init()` function outside of the `return` of my directive :

```
app.directive('myDirective', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        controller: function($scope)
        {
            init($scope);
        }
    }

    function init($scope) 
    {
        $scope.params = [];

        // Other initializations
    }
});
```

Is this bad practice or a bad idea? I just don't like to have the `init()` inside the `controller` since I feel that things inside the controller are meant to be reused and run continuously.

One of my reasoning for putting it at the end is that initialization happens once, and I want to place it at the very bottom of the code, where it doesn't bother me, and doesn't steal space from my other code that I spend more time on.

What do you think/suggest?

Comment: Its a matter of preference. Breaking up a bigger function so that it calls sub-functions through divide and conquer is a good strategy. Personally, I would prefer to put the init function inside of the controller function (limit the scope and move it so that it is closer to where it is used)

Comment: @micronyks, can you please explain why?

Comment: @micronyks Why, please?

Comment: @pixelbits, okay that makes sense. For me there are two reasons why I want it out: 1. I don't like indentation. 2. Initialization happens once, and it is the simple thing. I want to put it at the very bottom of the page as to not worry about it

Comment: @Kousha why not do the initialization in a link-function?

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen, as in only use initialization in the link function? I use `controller` for logic, and `link` for element binding. So I don't really see the difference of putting it in `link` or `controller`. What's your reasoning of placing it there?

Comment: @Kousha Sorry, I rushed the answer a little. I just realized the controller is instansiated before the link-function is run, so the suggestion is irrelevant :) I second pixelbits comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen patterns similar to yours many times, don't worry too much about it.  The only thing I would change is moving the initialization to the `link` function; the controller in directives is used to expose an API to other directive (used through `require`), so I wouldn't mix it with other stuff. I try to keep the API/communication part clean and initialize/bind stuff in the `link` function.

Comment: Thanks, and haha sorry but your name is link, and you prefer the link :p. I voted your answer for the explanation!